# $S(x)=\frac{x^4}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{x^6}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}+\frac{x^8}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8}+\cdots$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Find the sum of $$S(x)=\frac{x^4}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{x^6}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}+\frac{x^8}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8}+\cdots$$

What I did so far:

It's trivial that
$$S'(x)-xS(x)=\frac{x^3}{2}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!2^{{n(n+1)}/2}}$$

and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!2^{{n(n+1)}/2}}=0$$

Solve this ODE I got
$$S(x)=\frac{x^4}{8}e^x+Ce^x$$

And $S(x)=0$ , So $C=0$.

Finally, I got $S(x)=\frac{x^4}{8}e^x$

The problem is when I expand the function I got into power series, it looks different from the original one. So I may make some mistakes but I can't tell. Please help.

Comment: $S$ must be an even function since all powers are even.

Comment: @HenryW It seems that I made a mistake in solving ODE.

Comment: Write for example  the last term as $\frac{1}{4!} (x^2/2)^4$.

Comment: Forget the ODE. Note that $2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8=2^4\cdot4!$.

Answer (score 4):

The $r+2(r\ge0)$th term $$T_{r+2}=\dfrac{x^{2r}}{2^r r!}=\dfrac{(x^2/2)^r}{r!}$$

As $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!},$

$$\sum_{r=2}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2r}}{2^r r!}=e^{x^2/2}-T_0-T_1=?$$

Comment: Very fast, I should remember my Taylor Series next time :) Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your series seems to be missing some initial terms, right? Let $$T(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+S(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2\cdot4}+\cdots$$ Then you have $$T'(x)-xT(x)=0$$ with $T(0)=1$. So $T(x)=e^{x^2/2}$. And $S(x)=e^{x^2/2}-1-\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

@labbhattacharjee provided a very efficient approach to evaluating the series.

The approach in the OP did not provide a way forward since the solution to the ODE $S'(x)-xS(x)=\frac12x^3$, $S(0)=0$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
S(x)&=\int_0^x \frac12x'^3 e^{(x^2-x'^2)/2}\,dx' \tag 1\\\\
&=e^{x^2/2}-\frac12x^2-1
\end{align}$$

where we used the integrating factor $\mu(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ to facilitate generating the solution to the ODE and integration by parts to evaluate the integral in $(1)$.